# Usage Limit Clarification for Google Map Android API V2 and Google Place API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

Need some clarification on Google Map Usage Limit Policy.

1. While working an android app, i need to show google map to my users. So according to below image(taken from their policy), there are no usage limits..., so i can show it inside the app for free, doesn't matter how many downloads(or active user) it will have in future, right?

   Consider the fact, my app would be free in playstore to download, but it would show Admob advertisements, still i can use google map for free, right?

[image]

2. My app would also require google place api. As it isn't free after 1000 request/day, do i need to use an api key here different from Google Map Android API V2(as it is free according to above image)?

   For avoiding extra pricing, isn't that ok if i save responses from the very first request to the api and later use them without making any other request from same device, i mean is there any conflict with their policy?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API for Android has a daily limit of 1,000 requests per 24 hour period. Meaning everyday, your application can make 1,000 requests with the API. You don't need to use different API key with it because this 1,000 request limit is for the whole Project not per API key.

Note that the Google Places API for Android enforces a default limit of 1,000 requests per 24 hour period. If your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing and you need to [enable billing](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage#enable-billing) to get 150,000 requests per 24 hour period.

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/usage).

Comment: Yes i know about the billing and thanks for clearing api key's concern, can you clarify no. 1 issue? and also the later part of no. 2 point, is there any conflict with their policy if i save responses from the very first request to the api and later use them without making any furthur request from same device?